# Divide two polynomials using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to divide `p(x)` by `q(x)` given that:

```
p(x)=-5x^4+3x^2-6x
q(x)=x^2+1
```

I tried:

```
p=inline('-5*(x^4)+3*(x^2)','x')

p =
     Inline function:
     p(x) = -5*(x^4)+3*(x^2)

q=inline('x^2+1','x')

q =
     Inline function:
     q(x) = x^2+1

deconv(p,q)
```

but got error:

```
??? Undefined function or method 'filter' for input arguments of type 'inline'.

Error in ==> deconv at 32
   [q,zf] = filter(b, a, [1 zeros(1,nb-na)]);
```

WHY?

Comment: at least i tried, and got error stupid! then got problem, i asked here la...

Comment: @izzat: Are you just going to delete your question again after you get an answer?

Comment: What happened to the -6x in p(x)?

Answer (score 15):

Inline functions are just matlab expressions that it will evaluate. It has no idea whether they are polynomials or not.

You want this:

```
p = [-5 0 3 -6 0];
q = [2 0 1];

[quotient remainder] = deconv(p, q)
```

No need for Symbolic Math Toolbox here.

Comment: I suppose this is much more correct than the symbolic computations. I vote for this more correct answer )

Comment: this should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

`r = sym(p) \ sym(q)` would do the trick. The result would be a symbolic function, of course. To convert that to inline, `s = inline(r)`.

Edit:
As for the "WHY": you cannot divide two inline functions. Instead, they must first be converted to their symbolic representation.

Comment: got error:

 
>> r = sym(p) \ sym(q)


??? Undefined function or method 'sym' for input arguments of type 'inline'.

Comment: how to convert it to their symbolic representation?

Comment: I don't know why you are having this problem with 'sym' - it works fine here. Perhaps you are using an older version of MATLAB? I am on 7.9.0 (R2009b) and it works correctly.

Comment: @izzat - Do you have the Symbolic Math Toolbox installed? I believe that you need this to use sym().

Comment: Yes, sym() is part of the Symbolic Math Toolkit, that is why it does not work.